# How to test speed between web servers

Tags: php, webserver

my web pages are hosted on company A. I have moved to company B. My account at company A will be active for a few days. How can I test and therefore compare the speed of those two?

Thank you.

I am using webserver through cPanel, so I guess a PHP script or something would be great.

Comment: your are using webserver through CPanel doesnt matter. you want to compare the performances of two servers that are running on different companies boxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you test your web server speed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753376/how-can-you-test-your-web-server-speed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before:

See the 'hops' to your server with `traceroute` or `tracert`

There are some great server tools like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) which will give you a LOT of info about the server & network.

If they are your own servers you could even try a DDOS attack on them to see how much stress they can take.

You could simply run a php script with 50k loop iterations of different actions like file I/O, database queries etc etc to see how the 2 servers compare in milliseconds wit the different actions.

You could setup a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) script to run a few hundred ajax requests to see how each perform.

It really depends on what you suspect to be the problem? There are tools & methods to test each thing (network, hardware storage, cpu etc)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). easy to use. you can have some regression test for various scenarious which you actually want to do. ie: see how web servers perform under different loads and compare the companies.

Or you can use [Pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) even firebug will give you how long each web server takes to load the same resources.

Note that, your speed tet mostly will depend on latency, ie: your distance to one webserver vs the other one. Plus how many applications are running in one server on company A vs the other server on Company B if that s shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache have a look at `ab` the benchmarking tool.

Comment: I am using webserver through cPanel.

Comment: @arxanas Right - what better way to test a webserver - and there is no reason it cannot be run locally on the server.

Comment: @Kaoukkos cPanel is not a webserver

Answer (score 0):

You can also do *tracert* or *traceroute* depending on the OS you're using to test the actual connection speed. 
For the server speed itself, you can monitor your scripts directly inside of them (start a timer at the beginning of the load and display it when the page loading ends).

There are several things to consider on a "server speed", not only the horsepower :)